# Loading XML-file from URL

Tags: php, xml

I want to read a XML-file from an url and then retrieve the information from my XML-file.

```
<?php
  if( $_POST["name"])
  {
    ini_set('allow_url_fopen ','ON');
    $completeurl = "http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=".$_POST['name'];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file(file_get_contents($completeurl));  
    exit();
  }
?>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
  Search: <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I write some input to the form, it clearly manages to retrieve something, but I also get a message like this:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: 
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<response> <lst name="responseHeader"><int name="sta....
```

How can I extract the xml-info from the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file()` takes a filename, you'd want to use `simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($completeurl))` instead, or `simplexml_load_file($completeurl)`

Comment: I find it also worth to note that there is the stream context which allows for example to use POST requests and set custom HTTP headers which can be useful when talking to a REST API. You can find a simplexml example here: [OSM Data parsing to get the nodes with child](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16131157/367456)

Answer (score 4):

You are already having the remote file's contents in a string after calling `file_get_contents()`. Use [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) instead:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($completeurl));
```

But simpler would be to load the file directly using [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php). Note that the function supports HTTP urls:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

As above you are loading xml in from local host so you can give

```
simplexml_load_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uproYourFoldet/xml_data.xml')
```

you can also do this if you are using php version <5

```
$temp = file_get_contents($url);
 $XmlObj = simplexml_load_string($temp);
```