# Filtering xml records with attributes in php

Tags: php, xml

I have a file retrieved from a API pull request that looks something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis SNAPSHOT-r26564" xapi:planetDate="2014-10-07T15:42:02Z" xmlns:xapi="http://jxapi.openstreetmap.org/">
   <node id="251652819" version="6" timestamp="2013-10-19T14:03:10Z" uid="1198089" user="GeorgeKaplan" changeset="18434238" lat="48.8527413" lon="2.3333559">
     <tag k="dispensing" v="yes"/>
     <tag k="website" v="http://www.pharmacie-paris-citypharma.fr/"/>
     <tag k="name" v="Pharmacie Citypharma"/>
     <tag k="amenity" v="pharmacy"/>
  </node>
  <node id="251774849" version="9" timestamp="2014-07-28T21:28:26Z" uid="92075" user="Art Penteur" changeset="24411346" lat="48.8468043" lon="2.3696423">
     <tag k="phone" v="0143430996"/>
     <tag k="dispensing" v="yes"/>
     <tag k="name" v="Pharmacie de la Rapée"/>
     <tag k="amenity" v="pharmacy"/>
     <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Fr 08:30-20:30; Sa 09:00-19:30"/>
 </node>
 <node id="263262912" version="3" timestamp="2014-07-28T21:37:24Z" uid="92075" user="Art Penteur" changeset="24411346" lat="48.8446917" lon="2.3101829">
     <tag k="dispensing" v="yes"/>
     <tag k="amenity" v="pharmacy"/>
 </node>
 ....etc.
```

I am trying to filter the records based on the attributes, basically i am trying to retrieve the records that do not have a

```
    <tag k="name" v="blahblahblah"/> field.
```

I have been looking around and the classical way to do it its easy, however because of my poor skills in doing anything xml related i do have a couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to apply xml filtering for tags that look like this

   ```
   <tag k="dispensing" v="yes"/>
   ```

   ones that do not have the

   ```
    <tag></tag>
   ```

   format.
2. Also how can i filter the records when each child of the node has different attributes,like v, i would knew how to do it if it would look like this

   ```
     <tag k="name">Pharmacie de la Rapée</tag>
   ```

   but with the format received i can not see a way out on how to get the children that i need

Comment: Checkout `XPath` it will help you achieving what you want.

Comment: your xml is quite misleading. all your `<tag>` nodes are self closing

Comment: Related: [OSM Data parsing to get the nodes with child](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16129184/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all `<node>` elements that do not have a child `<tag>` with attribute `k="name"` you can use an [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) [query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) like `'//node[not(tag/@k="name")]'`

---

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis SNAPSHOT-r26564" xapi:planetDate="2014-10-07T15:42:02Z" xmlns:xapi="http://jxapi.openstreetmap.org/">
   <node id="251652819" version="6" timestamp="2013-10-19T14:03:10Z" uid="1198089" user="GeorgeKaplan" changeset="18434238" lat="48.8527413" lon="2.3333559">
     <tag k="dispensing" v="yes"/>
     <tag k="website" v="http://www.pharmacie-paris-citypharma.fr/"/>
     <tag k="name" v="Pharmacie Citypharma"/>
     <tag k="amenity" v="pharmacy"/>
  </node>
  <node id="251774849" version="9" timestamp="2014-07-28T21:28:26Z" uid="92075" user="Art Penteur" changeset="24411346" lat="48.8468043" lon="2.3696423">
     <tag k="phone" v="0143430996"/>
     <tag k="dispensing" v="yes"/>
     <tag k="name" v="Pharmacie de la Rapée"/>
     <tag k="amenity" v="pharmacy"/>
     <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Fr 08:30-20:30; Sa 09:00-19:30"/>
 </node>
 <node id="263262912" version="3" timestamp="2014-07-28T21:37:24Z" uid="92075" user="Art Penteur" changeset="24411346" lat="48.8446917" lon="2.3101829">
     <tag k="dispensing" v="yes"/>
     <tag k="amenity" v="pharmacy"/>
 </node>
 </osm>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//node[not(tag/@k="name")]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node);
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
<node id="263262912" version="3" timestamp="2014-07-28T21:37:24Z" uid="92075" user="Art Penteur" changeset="24411346" lat="48.8446917" lon="2.3101829">
     <tag k="dispensing" v="yes"/>
     <tag k="amenity" v="pharmacy"/>
 </node>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! Do you happen to know how to get the v attribute for each element that has a k="name" tag ?

Comment: Basically, how to access the exact tag k="name" child of $node element

Comment: i have tried doing that however the length of the list retrieved is 0 which is not ok, is there something that i am missing ?

Comment: Did almost the same thing http://screencast.com/t/myNpM9NwN1 . Do you happen to know what am i missing?

Comment: i do have one more question. i tried to do it alone, i looked everywhere but, for the life of me i  can not find the answer. Lets say i want to get the LAT and LON attributes for each node that has a tag k="name" child but also the value of v from the tag k="name", in the same time. How can that be done since there are no getChild() functions or things like that?

Comment: @user3253067: This has been outlined in the related question: [OSM Data parsing to get the nodes with child](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16129184/367456) - you can also find a comment there that you might not only be interested in `<node>` elements.